# Why isnt my seq2seq model reconising what the <END> tag is?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, tensorflow, sequence-to-sequence

I am making a seq2seq chatbot with the help of this guide: https://medium.com/predict/creating-a-chatbot-from-scratch-using-keras-and-tensorflow-59e8fc76be79 . I set up the model and data processing like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import yaml
import numpy as np
import requests, zipfile, io
import pickle
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import numpy as np
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras import layers , activations , models , preprocessing
import requests, zipfile, io
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)

dir_path = 'raw_data'
files_list = os.listdir(dir_path + os.sep)

questions = list()
answers = list()
for filepath in files_list:
    stream = open( dir_path + os.sep + filepath , 'rb')
    docs = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    conversations = docs['conversations']
    for con in conversations:
        if len( con ) > 2 :
            questions.append(con[0])
            replies = con[ 1 : ]
            ans = ''
            for rep in replies:
                ans += ' ' + rep

            answers.append(str(ans) + " end")
        elif len( con )> 1:
            questions.append(con[0])
            answers.append(str(con[1]) + " end")
a = []
for i in answers:
    a.append("start "+i)
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(questions + a)
encoder_input_data = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(questions), maxlen=22)
decoder_input_data = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(a), maxlen=74)
decoder_target_data = to_categorical(pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(answers), maxlen=74))

num_tokens = len( tokenizer.word_index )+1
word_dict = tokenizer.word_index
max_question_len = encoder_input_data.shape[1]
max_answer_len = decoder_input_data.shape[1]

print( 'Max length of question is {}'.format( max_question_len) )
print( 'Max length of answer is {}'.format( max_answer_len) )
print(num_tokens)
print( encoder_input_data.shape )
print( decoder_input_data.shape )
print( decoder_target_data.shape )

encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=( None , ))
encoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding( num_tokens, 200 , mask_zero=True) (encoder_inputs)
encoder_outputs , state_h , state_c = tf.keras.layers.LSTM( 200 , return_state=True )( encoder_embedding )
encoder_states = [ state_h , state_c ]

decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=( None ,  ))
decoder_embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding( num_tokens, 200 , mask_zero=True) (decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM( 200 , return_state=True , return_sequences=True )
decoder_outputs , _ , _ = decoder_lstm ( decoder_embedding , initial_state=encoder_states )
decoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense( num_tokens , activation=tf.keras.activations.softmax ) 
output = decoder_dense ( decoder_outputs )

model = tf.keras.models.Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], output )
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(), loss='categorical_crossentropy')


model.summary()

model.fit([encoder_input_data , decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data, batch_size=100, epochs=100 ) 
model.save( 'model.h5' ) 


def make_inference_models():

    encoder_model = tf.keras.models.Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

    decoder_state_input_h = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=( 200 ,))
    decoder_state_input_c = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=( 200 ,))

    decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]

    decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(
        decoder_embedding , initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
    decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
    decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
    decoder_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
        [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
        [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)

    return encoder_model , decoder_model

def str_to_tokens( sentence : str ):
    words = sentence.lower().split()
    tokens_list = list()
    for word in words:
        tokens_list.append( word_dict[ word ] ) 
    return preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences( [tokens_list] , maxlen=max_question_len , padding='post')


enc_model , dec_model = make_inference_models()

for _ in range(10):
    states_values = enc_model.predict( str_to_tokens( input( 'Enter question : ' ) ) )
    empty_target_seq = np.zeros( ( 1 , 1 ) )
    empty_target_seq[0, 0] = word_dict['start']
    stop_condition = False
    decoded_translation = ''
    while not stop_condition :
        dec_outputs , h , c = dec_model.predict([ empty_target_seq ] + states_values )
        sampled_word_index = np.argmax( dec_outputs[0, -1, :] )
        sampled_word = None
        for word , index in word_dict.items() :
            if sampled_word_index == index :
                decoded_translation += ' {}'.format( word )
                sampled_word = word

        if sampled_word == 'end' or len(decoded_translation.split()) > max_answer_len:
            stop_condition = True

        empty_target_seq = np.zeros( ( 1 , 1 ) )  
        empty_target_seq[ 0 , 0 ] = sampled_word_index
        states_values = [ h , c ] 

    print( decoded_translation )
```

It works with no errors, however the outputs when chatting are really bad, here is one of them:

```
Enter question : how are you

capacity normally again again again often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often often
```

Judging by the way it says the same word until it reaches the character limit, I think the model is not learning about the  tag. But I checked the data that is being processed for the encoder_target_data variable, and all the sentences ended in the end tag. I dont know why its not picking up on the end tag. How can I fix this?

Comment: If you refer the [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FKhOYhOz8d6BKLVVwL1YMlmoFQ2ML1DS#scrollTo=2zBmN8qB3O-e&forceEdit=true&offline=true&sandboxMode=true) , you will find that I have used GloVe embeddings for enhancing the performance. You can try using the GloVe embeddings and see if the model improves. The blog describes the model's basic construction so that you can explore the model yourself. Basically, the model requires more training if it can't predict the <end> tag.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I have tried the model with the pre-processed data in the notebook, it worked fine and I had no issues with it. How are you processing the target data?

Comment: It is the same as mentioned in the article. The difference is only of the GloVe embeddings. The code included in the article does not have an inclusion of GloVe vectors for simplicity. Whereas the notebook includes it. I insist you to refer the notebook. Also, could I link this answer in the Medium article which you read? It will help the other readers too.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal, Are you using just the keras to_categorical to one hot encode the decoder target data? When I one hot encode the data I get different dimensions than in the article, I get  (567, 74, 1910). Yes you can link this to the article.